# Java how do I use an incoming socket from the client several times

Tags: java, sockets, server, connection, client

So my question is when a socket connects is it possible to create two datainputstreams which both reference to 1 socket inputstream. I would like to print out text and text2 but this does not work.

Client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sender();
}

public Sender() {
    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1337);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Listen();
}

public Listen() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
        while(true) {
        Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
        System.out.println(socket.getPort() + ": " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream input2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String text = input.readUTF();
            String text2 = input2.readUTF();
            if(text != null) {
            System.out.println(text);
            }
            if(text2 != null) {
            System.out.println(text2);
            }
            //socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Comment: Please post more: a minimal, readable and functioning code sample. This is really short on everything

Comment: I don't think the code you provided is relevant to the problem you're talking about. You should probably post the portion of the code where the server handles connection requests from clients.

Comment: I changed the code in some smaller version to make it a bit clearer in what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You need a *loop*, that terminates on `EOFException`. And don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

```
input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
while(!formclosed) {
    try {
        String addtext = input.readUTF();
        addtext = formatText(addtext);
        logarea.setText(logarea.getText() + addtext);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("Client has disconnected.");
        return;
    } 
}
// any other IOException should be treated as an error
```

This should run as a background thread, not when you press a button.

Comment: The button was meant to open a new JFrame and then start a new background thread

Comment: Accepting connections in servers has nothing do with GUI buttons. It should be automatic.

Comment: It is already automatic accepted before the button click all the button does is start reading from the socket is this a bad idea?